# 2000 Volvo S40 startup pronlem

Tags: starting, volvo, s40

I tried to start my car today but I didn't want to start, last time I drove it it worked fine. The video at the bottom shows how it sounds at startup.

-3/-4 degrees celsius at the time this happened.

https://youtu.be/Dl8CWcbqHwc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like the battery not having enough juice to turn it over. At -3/-4C it's not that cold (just below freezing). Isn't going to hurt it much, but it does cause greater stress on the battery to try and start the vehicle.

Check the voltage at the battery. I'll bet you'll find it down around 10-11vdc. You may want to take it in to a parts store and get it load tested. Also check to ensure the posts are completely clean of corrosion. If they are corroded, clean them off, then put a battery charger on the battery, then try it again. If the battery is over five years old, it's probably time for a replacement anyway.

Comment: Maybe it's that, the battery is maybe 1 year and a month old so that would be weird tho.

Comment: @LiamRabe - Double check the connections to the battery cables on both ends. Make sure there's good contact. The noise is pretty easily discerned as a battery issue or at least not enough juice to turn the engine over.

Comment: Ok, I will check in to that tomorrow. Thanks for the help. :)